# Set an allowed device permanently in Microsoft YourPhone?

Tags: remote-access, remote, remote-control, remote-connection, your-phone

YourPhone is pretty sweet, except every d*mn time I go to use it it wants me to manually allow my PC to connect to it; the same (and only) PC I use every single time, which makes YourPhone useless as a remote control app because I still have to get up off my phat arse and go pick up my phone and mess with it, then go sit back down and use this "remote control" app.

So far I've been unable to find a way to set my computer as a permanently allowed device. Does anyone else know a way to do so?

*Ladies and gents, I present to you, arguably one of the most annoying screens in the known universe:*
[image]

Comment: @Ramhound aww, did I not phrase it in a serious enough, non-humorous tone for you? It's a legit question that has nothing to do with the UI design, it's a question on functionality and usability, and asking if anyone else knows of a way to do something I may not know how to do.

Comment: btw, it's also not just for a mobile app; it's a Microsoft Windows app that connects to another MS app on a mobile.